# Detecting if NSDate contains a weekend day

Tags: objective-c

I have this category added to NSDate:

```
- (bool)isWeekend
{
  NSString* s = [self asString:@"e"];

  if ([s isEqual:@"6"])
    return YES;
  else if ([s isEqual:@"7"])
    return YES;
  else 
    return NO;
}
```

Helper function:

```
- (NSString*)asString:(NSString*)format
{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
  NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
  [dateFormatter release];

  return formattedDateString;
}
```

`isWeekend` should return YES if it is a saturday or a sunday. But it does not work if the locale has a week start on a sunday, in which case friday will be day 6 and saturday will be day 7.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that 'asString:' creates an NSDateFormatter with the date format specified, then runs the NSDate through it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange weekdayRange = [calendar maximumRangeOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:aDate];
NSUInteger weekdayOfDate = [components weekday];

if (weekdayOfDate == weekdayRange.location || weekdayOfDate == weekdayRange.length) {
  //the date falls somewhere on the first or last days of the week
  NSLog(@"weekend!");
}
```

This is operating under the assumption that the first and last days of the week comprise the "week ends" (which is true for the Gregorian calendar.  It may not be true in other calendars).

Comment: I did not expect this solution to work. But it does. :-) For locales starting the week on a sunday, as well as those starting it on a monday. I must admit I don't understand the maximumRangeOfUnit:.

Comment: @Kobski the `maximumRangeOfUnit:` is basically to get how many days are in a week.

Comment: @dave-delong Thanks for taking the time to clarify this, but wouldn't that always be 7? I added some debug code just to see the values and for the locales I have tried, location is 1 and length is 7. But why should weekdayOfDate be 1 or 7 for it to be a weekend?

Comment: @Kobski in most modern calendars, yes it will always be 7.  However, there's no rule that says you can't create a calendar that has 42 days in a week (and other calendars may exist which don't have 7 days in a week).  The "1 or 7" check is really checking for "does this day fall on the first or the last day of the week", regardless of how many days there are in a week.

Comment: But very little software actually deals with those calendars, so it's almost always better to just say "7" and not make other people reading your code later have to figure extra stuff out.  When you don't have an actual problem to solve, simpler is better.

Comment: NSDateComponents always represent Sunday as first day and Saturday as the last one. That's why it works.

Comment: The [UAE works from Sunday to Thursday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend). How to cover this case?

Comment: As of iOS 8, use `isDateInWeekend:` on `NSCalendar`

Answer (score 18):

As of iOS 8, you can use `isDateOnWeekend:` on `NSCalendar`.

Comment: should be isDateInWeekend

Answer (score 9):

In **Swift 3+**:

```
extension Date {
  var isWeekend: Bool {
    return NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!.isDateInWeekend(self)
  }
}
```

Comment: @Yohst ha, yes! Swift can be pretty concise :)

Answer (score 5):

In Swift:

```
func isWeekend(date: NSDate) -> Bool {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    return calendar.isDateInWeekend(date)
}
```