# Using this week and weekend to check in between 2 NSDates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

The NSDate part of my assignment requires me to display events according to the category the user chooses. The categories are - today, this month, this week, and this weekend. I've done both 'today' and 'this month' and I'm having trouble with the other two. Basically I have a date range for every event (e.g fromDate = 03-04-2011 , toDate = 03-11-2011). What I want to do is check if this week and this weekend falls in between the date range. I've googled for sources but couldn't find what I need. I understand that I have to use the NSCalendar but I don't know how to go about it.

[Detecting if NSDate contains a weekend day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426122/detecting-if-nsdate-contains-a-weekend-day)

^ The answer seems to be what I'm looking for but I have no idea how to use it. Any help on that or any other solution will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)checkForWeekend:(NSDate *)aDate {
  BOOL isWeekendDate = NO;
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSRange weekdayRange = [calendar maximumRangeOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit];
  NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:aDate];
  NSUInteger weekdayOfDate = [components weekday];

  if (weekdayOfDate == weekdayRange.location || weekdayOfDate == weekdayRange.length) {
    // The date falls somewhere on the first or last days of the week.
    isWeekendDate = YES;
  }
  return isWeekendDate;
}
```

USAGE:

```
BOOL isWeekend = [self checkForWeekend:[NSDate date]]; // Any date can be passed here.

if (isWeekend) {
  NSLog(@"Weekend date! Yay!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Is there a way to get the NSDate of this weekend? I need the dates to compare with my event dates to check if they fall in between.