# Sort an array of dates to extract every sundays

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am quite new to ios and I was wondering how one could from a NSMutableArray of dates ( as strings) extract all the sundays in that array.

So far from my research I found that I have to start from the date of today like this

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

Then "select" the sundays like that

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit |       NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];    
NSInteger weekday = [dateComponents 1]; // 1 is sunday right ?!
```

Then go back into the past and every sunday put the date in a new array or else.

```
   NSDate *dateRelease;
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [ [ NSDateFormatter alloc ] init ];
   [ dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"] ];
   [ dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd" ];

   for (int i = [ dateFormatter dateFromString:[[[[DessinsManager sharedInstance]imagesList].count ; i > 0; i--){

     dateRelease = [ dateFormatter dateFromString:[[[[DessinsManager sharedInstance]imagesList] objectAtIndex:i]dateDrawing] ];

     //Check for the sundays here 
     if ( [now compare: dateRelease] == NSOrderedDescending  ) {
     //if sundays put in new array
     } else {
     //if not sundays then go on with loop
     }   
   }
```

And for this I am a bit confused on how to do the comparaison to get the sundays (my array goes from november 1st 2013 till today)...

Thanks for your help

V.v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the dates as `NSDate` objects as you should always store data using the most appropriate data type:

```
NSArray *datesAsStrings = ...;
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray new];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
for (NSString *dateStr in datesAsStrings) {
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    [dates addObject:dates];
}
```

and then filter out the sundays:

```
NSMutableArray *sundays = [NSMutableArray new];
[dates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)) {
    NSDate *date = (NSDate *)obj;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                          fromDate:date];
    if (comps.weekday == 1)
        [sundays addObject:date];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the example even though I didn't reuse it completely, I got the idea !

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` method, which returns a new array evaluating each object in the original one with a predicate.

Such a predicate may be built with `+ (NSPredicate *)predicateWithBlock:(BOOL (^)(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings))block` and maybe some inspiration from [Dave DeLong's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426122/detecting-if-nsdate-contains-a-weekend-day#answer-5426366) to recognise the day being evaluated.